# asp.net core 2 rewrite rules for an angular app

Tags: angular, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm running an angular (5) app in a self hosted asp.net core2 application. I put the useHash option to false. I also use an external identity service (okta) which uses a return url after login. This url doesn't work because it is not rewritten to index.html where the angular app runs.

I'm trying to make a rewrite rule with UseRewriter but I can't get it to work.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var options = new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRewrite("source", "destination", true);
        app.UseRewriter(options);

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
```

What I basically want is to rewrite everything to index.html except for existing files, like it is possible in IIS rewrites with isFile and negate=true. See example below. How can I do that?

```
<match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^api/" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/index.html" />
```

Comment: I see now that I made a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604007/make-angular-routes-work-inside-asp-net-core-2-0-app?rq=1 which directed me to https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-fix-the-routing-225ac90f to fix the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Angular routes work inside ASP.NET Core 2.0 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604007/make-angular-routes-work-inside-asp-net-core-2-0-app)