# ASP.NET Core routing ignore Angular 5 routing calls when deep linking

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm running ASP.NET Core MVC for the API calls. Routing: api/*
Also running Angular 5.x with its own routing model.

Things work great running localhost (Core runs port 5000 and angular 4200). But when the project is released on Azure everything runs on port 443.

When the application is released all routing goes through the ASPNET Core routing causes 404 when **deep linking**.

How do I configure the ApplicationBuilder to redirect the Angular routing to Angular?

### update:

Links to API:

- /api/event/{id}
- /api/event/{id}/thing

Links to angular:

- /  --> (home)
- /event/{key}
- /event/{key}/thing

When traveling from the Home (/) page and using the angular routing the user redirects to /event/{key} which works. When refreshing (F5) the API routing kicks in and returns 404 (because the api doesn't understand).

### update2:

This is the fix:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc();                             // <-- moved to top (was on bottom)
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/"); // <-- added to redirect to angular
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
```

Comment: Is your set up a single deployment i.e. your bundled angular code is in a folder inside your api project? If so, do you have any pipeline code to return index.html if the request isn't an api request?

Comment: Yes, it is a single deployment. I'm trying to work out how to distinguish the api and index.html code in sturtup.cs. At the moment reading http://blog.nbellocam.me/2016/03/21/routing-angular-2-asp-net-core/ but it older version.

Comment: You'll need to create a custom middleware, that executes for each request. If the request doesn't start with /api/, then you return your index.html file. After that, all non api routes should be handled by the Angular router. There is a good explanation here https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-core-demystified-middleware/.

Comment: You must be using a pretty outdated template. The newer ASP.NET Core 2.0 templates use webpack bundling and serve the the angular application as static files from  `wwwroot` root folder which is always registered first before the MVC middleware (unless you changed that which would make not much sense)

Comment: @tseng well the routing works except when deeplinking.

Comment: @tseng I'm using dotnetcore 2.1.4 from januari, downloading newer version to see if anything has changed.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute()` fixed the routing problems.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMvc();                             // <-- moved to top (was on bottom)
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/"); // <-- added to redirect to angular
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```